# Running Java code to Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop

Given a java program which works with files, is possible to run it in hadoop environment exploiting the parallelism of the cluster?

this is an example of pseudocode:

```
    A = read.flespi  // Read one record from FLESPI File

 B = read.fltquo // Read one record from  FLTQUO File



while( flespi != EOF ) /* Until flespi is not finished */

{

                If( A.I1-codice-titolo-int ==B. WTQ01C-COD-TIT-INT )

                {

                                PERFORM E200-IMPOSTA-CAMPI-OUTPUT   ();   /* Write output */

                               A = read.flespi  // Leggo record da file FLESPI

                                B = read.fltquo // Leggo record da file FLTQUO

                               Continue;

                }

                If( A.I1-codice-titolo-int > B. WTQ01C-COD-TIT-INT )

                {              B = read.fltquo // 

                               Continue;                        

               }

                If( A.I1-codice-titolo-int < B. WTQ01C-COD-TIT-INT )

                {              /* Write output in some way */

                               WRITE…

                                A = read.flespi; //              

                               Continue;            

               }



}
```

As you can see, it process 2 files in the meanwhile.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can observe parallelism, you can use  multiple input paths in hadoop for processing multiple files in hadoop

Comment: My java program is not map reduce one. Are you Telling me it does not matter ??

Comment: Yes, it does not matter.You can keep the  logic of java program in Mapper and Reducer phase and your data in the files is split across the nodes in the cluster (while loading). So parallel process can be observed while running map reduce program. But by the way what is the logic of your java program?

Comment: I have edited my question to show you an example of my code.
Anyway, I do not understand if I need to rebuild it using map&Reduce paradigm or if there is a way to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem sounds to me like this, you are taking the data from two files and comparing the values from two files and writing it to the other files(?). You can have a look into Mapside join or Reduce side join to perform this using MulitpleInput paths and Multiple Output Paths

Answer (score 0):

you can find a nice tutorial on this at http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Reduce-side-join-in-hadoop-%3A-Data-analyses-from-different-types-of-data-sources